# Why is Rin's butler Emiya Shirou in UBW true ending?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In the UBW true ending it is stated (in the anime) that Shirou is Rin's butler. 
I assume they took it from Fate Hollow Ataraxia (the butler part). Why is that? Does Rin enjoy making Shirou be and feel beneath her or something?

New informtion due to the discussions that have taken place

I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding and not explainig well my question. 
E..tto... I was asking something similar to what Lord was talking about. I used the word butler on purpose and I mentioned Fate Hollow Ataraxia on purpose as well. In fate hollow it is confirmed that Shirou works for Lluvia as a part-time job [to be able to eat without resorting to Rin I take it]. However, in the anime they changed it, Lluvia's words make it clear he's now Rin's butler, not Lluvia's. My questions remain being "Why is that?" and "Does Rin enjoy making Shirou be and feel beneath her or something?"

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 possibilities. Either they made a mistake or they changed it. They've made quite a few changes and Nasu said those changes are canon (an alternative universe) so it could very well be a better adaptation of their situation in London in which both Rin and Shirou spend a lot of time together.

If that's the case I'd say there are 2 reasons.

1. Because she's crazy possesive and selfish. I lost count of how many times she said "You're mine" in the VN, even outside her route.
2. This is IMO 90% of the reason. Because of Shirou's personality and circumstances. From the very beginning in the VN Shirou is doing part-time jobs to be able to pay for his daily expenses. It is stated he could stop doing them but he doesn't want to be a freeloader. 
   What happens in London is that he feels compelled to pay for the food, travel expenses... and he no longer has the part-time job income as he's not in Japan doing them. It would only be natural for him to look for work in London.

My guess is that in the anime Rin pretty much forced him to take the job. That way everyone wins: Rin gets to spend a lot of time with Shirou (otherwise he'd be all day working outside the magic lessons), he takes her to places to spend time together, he does things like cooking and Rin would paying for everything while they're together in London.
I'm pretty sure Shirou would have accepted even if he wasn't paid, so I wouldn't say Rin is taking advantage of him.

Edit: I've been looking for it for 15 minutes and finally found it. Just so that you know the jobs he's doing in Japan are not a breeze, this is one of them:

> A simple loading job from five to eight o'clock. Even though it's only three hours, there's six hours worth of work to do. They make you run around without a minute's rest.

Moreover, Fuji-nee is constantly telling him not to arrive too late at night because of work. The only reason you don't see him working in the VN is because he gives up those part-time jobs because of the war (it makes sense...) but in reality his time is 99% school, part-time jobs and chores he does for free.

Comment: You make some overly board assumption without any citations. In the True End of UBW, Rin and Shirou are romantically involved. Shirou voluntarily joins her at the Clock Tower,  in part to be with her and in part to further his magecraft. The anime makes some embellishments in the epilogue,  but the general course of events and motivations stay the same.

Comment: I like the way you explain reason 2, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @кяαzє "The anime makes some embellishments in the epilogue" I don't know how you mean to use the word embelishment. If you intend to say they add new details, then I completely agree to you. However, if you want to say they make Rin more romantically involved that wouldn't be true. The main source of the episode is Mimic Rin II (from fate hollow ataraxia) and it is shown Rin is completely love-struck. @ Arthur Pendragon ^_^

Comment: @Lord All F/SN routes and F/HA happen in alternative universes of sorts. That's how Nasu's multiverse works - it's made up of several alternative sub-universes, so even mutually exclusive routes are all "true" or canon. By embellishment I mean derivative of the source material it's adapted from. If you want to continue this conversation, you are welcome do so in chat. The comments aren't a place for extended discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Lord's answer is incorrect and subjective.

Shirou joins Rin as her apprentice. Tohsaka, being from a prominent magus lineage and having significant in-born talent (affinity to the 5 elements) , and having recieved a special recommendation from Lord El-Melloi II to join the Clock Tower. Those who recieve these special recommendations are given special privileges,  such as individual dorms and be allowed to bring an apprentice:

> "A mage has the right to be accompanied by a follower or pupil for their protection. You're enrolled here as my follower, so act a little more dignified. I know that. I'm grateful to you, Tohsaka. You ought to be. Getting you in wasn't easy. Well, it's only a three-year special exemption"
>
> "I've been invited as the Tohsaka heir. They say I can bring a pupil with me if I want to"
>
> <sub>Quotes from episode 25</sub>

Mage apprentices don't have go through the examinations to enter the Clock Tower, but they won't be seen as members of the Mages Association.

The current finances of the Tohsaka family is being by covered by the patent royalties that are being transferred to their account managed by the Mages Association.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46235/discussion-on-answer-by-z-why-is-rins-butler-emiya-shirou-in-ubw-true-endi).